# Dealing with tuples in Javascript: container data structures

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

For whatever reason, the algorithms I am writing deal with tuples of numbers (think strings of a fixed length, but each character is a number). For instance, if today the lengths of my tuples are 4, I want an abstract data similar to

```js
// Think of Vector<Tuple<4>>
const vector_of_tuples = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 4, 6],
  [9, 8, 7, 2],
  [5, 6, 7, 8],
];
```

Tuples of numbers (of a fixed length) are now my basic datatype, and I want to make vectors out of them, use them as keys in maps, and so on. (Using them as keys in maps is a question for another day).

If my code creates new vectors of tuples many times, it creates a lot of garbage, since each tuple allocates its own storage. Creating a vector with n tuples causes O(n) allocations. An obvious win on this front would be to "pack" the tuples into a single vector (remove the square brackets in the example above):

```js
const packed_vector_of_tuples = [
  0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 1, 4, 6,
  9, 8, 7, 2,
  5, 6, 7, 8
];
```

This is a big win in terms of allocations (O(1) rather than O(n) for a vector holding n tuples), but a big loss in terms of usability. Obviously now I need to remember the lengths of the tuples somehow (not a problem, easily solved), but abstraction becomes much more difficult. Suppose I now want to iterate over my packed vector of tuples, similar to how `vector_of_tuples.forEach(...)` would have originally worked. One idea is to do it like this:

```js
function forEach_packed_vector(packed_vector, tuple_length, func) {
  for (let i = 0; i < packed_vector.length; i += tuple_length)
    func(packed_vector.slice(i, i + tuple_length));
}
```

However, this means that each time I iterate I do O(n) allocations, exactly the thing I tried to avoid. (Both V8 and SpiderMonkey seem to not be able to pass a short vector on the stack, or at least to sufficient escape analysis to work with my code).

I could instead reserve my own "stack allocated" working space:

```js
function forEach_packed_vector_2(packed_vector, tuple_length, func) {
  const temporary = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < packed_vector.length; i += tuple_length) {
    // Copy packed_vector[i : i + tuple_length] into temporary.
    for (let j = 0; j < tuple_length; j++)
      temporary[j] = packed_vector[i + j];

    // Now call the iteration function.
    func(temporary);
  }
}
```

This in fact works quite well, does not allocate more than once, and is incredibly fast. However, I keep running into bugs where `func` holds onto a reference to the vector passed in (rather than taking a defensive copy, as it should), which leads to some very very strange bugs manifesting themselves elsewhere in my code. So this solution is great in terms of performance and quite terrible in terms of being able to shoot yourself in the foot.

> **Question:** How can I write performant, garbage-light code like this without setting myself traps for later?

This problem is basically begging for a slice type, like `Span<T>` in C#, or slices in Go, etc. But I would be open to any and all suggestions about how to create efficient data structures like this in a way that lends itself nicely to abstraction without leaving footguns.

Comment: Might be better suited for [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 2):

As you are probably well aware, there is no "slice type" in JavaScript.

You can build your own:

```
class Slice {
  constructor(array, start, length) {
    this.array = array;
    this.start = start;
    this.length = length;
  }
  get(index) {
    return this.array[this.start + index];
  }
  /* any other methods you want */
}

function func(slice) {
  for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
    console.log(slice.get(i));
  }
}

func(new Slice(packed_vector_of_tuples, 4, 4));
```

Of course you'd allocate any time you create such a slice, but especially if your tuples are much bigger than 4 elements, this might be a reasonable compromise between abstraction and efficiency -- in particular, it's O(1) per allocation, whereas `Array.prototype.slice` has to allocate *and then copy `n` elements*.

((EDIT: to expand on this: you could further reduce the number of allocations by caching the slices on the outer container, roughly like this:

```
class PackedVector {
  constructor(tuple_length, tuple_count, tuple_data) {
    console.assert(tuple_data.length === tuple_length * tuple_count);
    this.array = tuple_data;
    this.slices = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < tuple_count; i++) {
      this.slices[i] = new Slice(this.array, i * tuple_length, tuple_length);
    }
    this.length = tuple_count;
  }
}

function forEach_packed_vector_3(packed_vector, func) {
  for (let i = 0; i < packed_vector.length; i++)
    func(packed_vector.slices(i));
}
```

END OF EDIT))

For maximum performance, the `packed_vector_of_tuples` is a good idea, and any helper functions could consume an "unboxed" version of the `Slice` class above. So instead of `func(temporary)`, you'd have `func(base_array, start, length)`. That would guard against the "accidental reference" class of bugs, but would make the function signatures relatively unwieldy.

From your description, it sounds like having object identity of the individual tuples is important for your larger application. If that's indeed the case, I would recommend to go with your very first solution: an array of arrays. Sure, there'll be a bit of overhead; but until you notice that that actually matters, it doesn't matter (and my prediction is that it won't; allocations are cheap, and the longer the tuple the smaller the relative overhead).

Comment: Thanks very much for your comments! The application which is using these is actually using very short tuples (all between 2 and 5 elements, basically), and basically uses maps of tuples to integers. (They are representing multivariate polynomials, for example x^2 y^4 - 3 x z^7 would be a map {[2, 4, 0] => 1, [1, 0, 7] => -3}). These polynomials get used in long calculations with many useless intermediate results in a very fire-and-forget fashion, and I was finding (on Firefox in particular) that over 30% of my running time was GC. Hence the switch to "packed" structures...

Comment: ... but writing a "packed" performant map is quite involved. And then in changing the iteration interfaces to not allocate I hit all these other bugs I set myself up for :P. I actually quite like the slice idea as an interface, so the data structure holds one mutable slice throughout the iteration.

Comment: Not sure I follow the notation of your example... is the map used for keeping track of counts/coefficients? How about storing those as a field on the object instead? Maps do require object identity on the keys. -- Regarding slices, you could avoid allocations by caching them; I'll work that into my answer as it's easier to read there.

Comment: Yes, the map key should represent a monomial, (eg [1,2,1] might represent x y^2 z), and the associated value is the coefficient. I want to add, subtract, multiply these (amongst other things). When I say “map”, I don’t mean any kind of specific javascript object, I mean the abstract idea of a key associated to a value - in particular I want keys to be equal based on equality of contents, not equality of objects. The fact that some of these polynomials have 100-1000 entries means that multiplication allocates like crazy if there is an object per monomial.